# I've bid 1ETH for ENS domain and was the only bidder - revealed during the 48 hours period - how do I get the refund?

Tags: ens

Please have a look at tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4831dbed82aaf859b484beae26ed8a24be2fce4c3912a5958d0b35950a72c90e

It seems like I've correctly revealed my bid:

[image]

**How do I get the refund?**

Tried checking internal transactions but nothing there...

Full history of my account: https://etherscan.io/address/0x85A363699C6864248a6FfCA66e4a1A5cCf9f5567 - you'll see two recent transactions to ENS.

---

## **EDIT:**

http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/faq.html

> If only one bid is revealed, that bidder deposits 0.01 ether, the minimum bid. The remainder of their bid is refunded as soon as they finalise the auction.

**How to finalise the auction?**

Answer (score 2):

You finalize the auction by [calling `finalizeAuction` on the ENS .eth registrar contract](https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#finalizing-the-auction).

The example code in the ENS docs uses web3.js:

```
ethRegistrar.finalizeAuction(web3.sha3('name'), {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000});
```

If you prefer a specific tool or language to make a transaction, please update the question.

Comment: I will use https://etherscan.io/address/0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef#writeContract `writeContract` option on Ethercan in combination with MetaMask. Thank you, I think it should be added to FAQ. Non obvious...